# Regex to select seconds from time string (all times not in the same format) without lookbehind

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to select the seconds in a time string. The seconds will always be followed by a comma but the time may or may not include seconds.

So for the following example:

```
01-01-01 01:01:00, some text
01-01-01 01:01:01, more text
01-01-01 01:01, ignore me please
01-01-01 01:01:32, text
```

The regex would select:

```
:00
:01
:32
```

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `/\d\d:\d\d(:\d\d)/g` selects `01:01:00` and would capture `:00`, this applies to all situations accept `01-01-01 01:01, ignore me please` which is ignored.